# PHP preg_filter() substitute in PHP<5.3?

Tags: php, regex, function

Had to deploy some PHP code onto a shared server with only PHP5.2.8.  All code works EXCEPT for the `preg_filter()` call which was added in 5.3+ (and against which the code was written).

Can anyone recommend an easy substitute for `preg_filter()` in PHP5.2?

Comment: Code you paste a sample code please? It would be much easier to help you

Comment: Hah, this is the first 5.3 function I see that does not have a dozen workarounds in the comments in the manual! If I understand correctly what it does, it should be fairly straightforward to convert to using preg_match for this, though.

Comment: Creating a true polyfill for `preg_filter()` will be much more convoluted than merely calling `preg_replace()`then `array_diff()`because `preg_filter()` is designed to process flat arrays AND scalar data.  See the examples at [preg_replace() versus preg_filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197390/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP manual says that `preg_filter()` is identical to `preg_replace()` except it only returns the matches.

So, you can use a combination of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) to get results like preg_filter in PHP 5.2.x. Do it like this:

```
<?php
$subject = array('1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'A', 'B', '4'); 
$pattern = array('/\d/', '/[a-z]/', '/[1a]/'); 
$replace = array('A:$0', 'B:$0', 'C:$0'); 

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
var_dump($result);

//take difference of preg_replace result and subject
$preg_filter_similar = array_diff($result, $subject);

var_dump($preg_filter_similar);
?>
```

This gives the output (with xDebug installed):

```
array
  0 => string 'A:C:1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'B:C:a' (length=5)
  2 => string 'A:2' (length=3)
  3 => string 'B:b' (length=3)
  4 => string 'A:3' (length=3)
  5 => string 'A' (length=1)
  6 => string 'B' (length=1)
  7 => string 'A:4' (length=3)
array
  0 => string 'A:C:1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'B:C:a' (length=5)
  2 => string 'A:2' (length=3)
  3 => string 'B:b' (length=3)
  4 => string 'A:3' (length=3)
  7 => string 'A:4' (length=3)
```

Which is same as [`preg_filter()` output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

```
Array
(
    [0] => A:C:1
    [1] => B:C:a
    [2] => A:2
    [3] => B:b
    [4] => A:3
    [7] => A:4
)
```

Comment: It seems to be recursive, setting `$limit` of `preg_replace` to `1` does not helps - see the first two lines of results: for example the first line matching to `A` (contains digits), then the *result itself* matching to `C` (contains the character `1`).

Comment: Here is just one of many ways that this code does not duplicate the behavior of `preg_filter()`: https://3v4l.org/Q21WV