# preg_replace() versus preg_filter()

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-filter

What are the differences between `preg_replace()` and `preg_filter()`?

In which situations should I use one instead of the other?

I tried reading the documentation, but still don't quite understand what the differences are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preg_filter() is identical to preg_replace() except it only returns the (possibly transformed) subjects where there was a match. For details about how this function works, read the preg_replace() documentation.

from: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php)

So if the signature is

```
preg_filter ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , 
              mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

it returns the `$subject` arguments "transformed" (all the match with `regex pattern` are substitute) into an array

Comment: Are there any advantages when using one of them instead of the other in certain situations?

Comment: @Marco Leonardo Yamin - Yes, if you only care about those where a match/replacement occurred.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of `preg_filter` over `preg_replace` is that you can check whether or not anything was replaced, because `preg_filter` returns null if nothing was replaced, while `preg_replace` returns the subject regardless.

```
$subject = 'chips';
$pattern = '/chops/';
$replacement = 'flops';

if (is_null(preg_filter($pattern, $replacement, $subject)) { // true
    // do something
}

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject); // 'chips'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Both functions can process string-type (well, [scalar-type values](https://3v4l.org/TrBnD)) input or a flat array and are primarily designed to return string or array type data -- depending on the input data-type. If [`preg_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) receives a string but it does not satisfy the regex logic, then `null` will be returned.  With either function, if there is an error, `null` will be returned.
2. [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will mutate the data, but has no ability to remove elements; the only reason to ever use `preg_filter()` is when you wish to mutate the input value(s) AND remove the unaffected value(s).
3. `preg_filter()` behaves like `preg_replace()` followed by a destructive step where unchanged values are either removed from the array or the string is converted to `null`. Like `preg_replace()`, `preg_filter()` has the ability to optionally limit replacements per string and count the number of replacements performed in the entire process.

Array test: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iHFSS))

```
$array = [
    " happens",
    "I'm getting too old for this ",
    "shiitake",
    "Mondays are , Tuesdays are , and so on!",
    "Here is your Finnish itinerary",
    "Is this chocolate or ?"
];
var_export(
    preg_filter('//u', 'poop', $array, 1, $count)  // parameters 4 and 5 are optional
);
echo "\n---\ncount: $count";
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'poop happens',
  1 => 'I\'m getting too old for this poop',
  3 => 'Mondays are poop, Tuesdays are , and so on!',
  5 => 'Is this chocolate or poop?',
)
---
count: 4
```

---

String Tests: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fa3Rd))

```
var_export(
    preg_filter('//u', 'poop', "Mondays are , Tuesdays are , and so on!", 1, $count)
);
echo "\n---\ncount: $count\n===\n";

var_export(
    preg_filter('//u', 'poop', "shiitake", 1, $count)
);
echo "\n---\ncount: $count";
```

Output:

```
'Mondays are poop, Tuesdays are , and so on!'
---
count: 1
===
NULL
---
count: 0
```