# How PHP preg_filter works?

Tags: php

can anyone please explain how this code works?

```
<?php
$subject = array('1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'A', 'B', '4'); 
$pattern = array('/\d/', '/[a-z]/', '/[1a]/'); 
$replace = array('A:$0', 'B:$0', 'C:$0'); 

echo "preg_filter returns\n";
print_r(preg_filter($pattern, $replace, $subject));
?>
```

Why is the output like this? :

```
preg_filter returns
Array
(
    [0] => A:C:1
    [1] => B:C:a
    [2] => A:2
    [3] => B:b
    [4] => A:3
    [7] => A:4
)
```

I got this from the PHP site and I'm trying to understand how this code works.

Comment: See also [preg_replace() versus preg_filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197390/2943403) for more explanations and demonstrations of `preg_filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example the same elements in the original array are matched and replaced. However, `preg_filter()` doesn’t return the `5` and `6` elements because they didn’t match any of the patterns.

As stated in the documentation...

> It works just like [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace), except it only returns the (possibly transformed) subjects where there was a match.

Comment: Please just explain how that patterns work. I don't know how to use them or how create a pattern.

Comment: @RollieOsayan there is documentation for that sort of thing. Stackoverflow is meant for asking specific questions - not just saying "explain this to me". The docs and google are good for that.