# How to specify regex search group?

Tags: php, regex

I want replace my custom creted tag to implement JS script wiht `preg_filter`:

```
preg_filter(
    "/<!--@SCRIPT-->.*$<!--@SCRIPT-->/", 
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="$0"></script>', 
    '<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->
);
```

from:
`<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->`

am getting:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->"></script>`

How to rewrite that regex to have `$0` group without surrounding `<!--@SCRIPT-->`?

In other words how to narrow this group to get:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a capturing group `(...)` to extract the content between tags. Then you can refer to it in the replacement string with `$1`.

```
$result = preg_filter('~<!--@SCRIPT-->([^<]*)<!--@SCRIPT-->~', 
                      '<script type="text/javascript" src="$1"></script>', 
                      '<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->');
```

This works in our specific case, however I'm not sure that `preg_filter()` is a good choice to accomplish this task since it returns an empty string if there is no match. Better to use `preg_replace()` in the same way:

```
$result = preg_replace('~<!--@SCRIPT-->([^<]*)<!--@SCRIPT-->~', 
                       '<script type="text/javascript" src="$1"></script>', 
                       '<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->');
```

Comment: And what's `$0` here?

Comment: @Ultra: the `$0` represents the whole match (all the string in our case), you don't need it.

Comment: `preg_filter()` actually returns `null` if there is no match from a string-type input.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197390/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
preg_filter(
"/<!--@SCRIPT-->(.*?)<!--@SCRIPT-->/", 
'<script type="text/javascript" src="$1"></script>', 
'<!--@SCRIPT-->/test.js<!--@SCRIPT-->'
)
/* OUTPUT */
string '<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>' (length=55)
```