# Add height attribute to <img> tags using getimagesize()

Tags: php, html, image, replace

I want to alter my `post_content` string so that all `<img>` tags have a height attribute with a value derived from the image.

`preg_match_all doesn't suit my needs.

I've tried `preg_filter()`, but I can't call a function in the replacement parameter.

`getimagesize(IMGURL)[1]` is the height size pixel.

`$2` is intented to be the img tag src URL in the replacement string.

```
preg_filter(
    '/<img(.+?)src="(.+?)"(.+?)>/i',
    "<img$1src=\"$2\"$3 height=\"" . getimagesize("{$2}")[1] . "\">",
    $row['post_content']
);

// <img src="/abc/a.jpg" height="">

preg_filter(
    '/<img(.+?)src="(.+?)"(.+?)>/i',
    "<img$1src=\"$2\"$3 height=\"".getimagesize(."{$2}".)[1]."\">",
    $row['post_content']
);

// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /var/www/a/a.php line 22
```

My input string declaration:

```
$row['post_content'] = <<<HTML
<p>Hello my name is.</p>
<img src="sadsafdsd.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadsafdsfd.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadsgtjhsad.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="hgtsadsad.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadshtread.jpg" width="400" alt><br>
<img src="sadretsad.jpg" alt><br>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_replace_callback() instead.

```
function setheight($matches){
    $img_prop = getimagesize($matches[2]);
    return '<img' . $matches[1] . 'src="'.$matches[2].'" '. $matches[3] . ' height="'.$img_prop[2].'">';
}

preg_replace_callback(
            "/<img(.+?)src=\"(.+?)\"(.+?)>/i",
            "setheight",
            $row['post_content']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `preg_filter()` does not modify a string by reference. You snippet doesn't use the function's return value and I think it is important to explain that the mutated value is returned by the function.
2. `preg_filter()` is appropriate to call on a string IF you want use regex to replace some thing(s) AND you want to reduce the string to `null` if there are no replacements. See also: [preg_replace() versus preg_filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197390/2943403)
3. It is less reliable, often under-considered, and less intuitive to use regex to process parsable HTML. Instead use a native DOM parsing library such as DOMDocument. The DOMDoument class offers self-explanatory method names and much more accurate results versus regex.
4. Because your input string is missing a parent (containing) element (child elements need a parent), you can temporarily wrap the string in a basic div tag, perform the changes, then remove the div tag to prevent the parser from making assumptions about how your content should be remedied.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/90BkQ))

```
$row['post_content'] = <<<HTML
<p>Hello my name is.</p>
<img src="sadsafdsd.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadsafdsfd.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadsgtjhsad.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="hgtsadsad.jpg" alt><br>
<img src="sadshtread.jpg" width="400" alt><br>
<img src="sadretsad.jpg" alt><br>
HTML;

// spoof native function for demo
function _getimagesize($src) {
    return [0, 100];
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<div>{$row['post_content']}</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img) {
    $img->setAttribute(
        'height',
        getimagesize(
            $img->getAttribute('src')
        )[1]
    );
}
echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), 5, -7);
```

Output:

```
<p>Hello my name is.</p>
<img src="sadsafdsd.jpg" alt height="100"><br>
<img src="sadsafdsfd.jpg" alt height="100"><br>
<img src="sadsgtjhsad.jpg" alt height="100"><br>
<img src="hgtsadsad.jpg" alt height="100"><br>
<img src="sadshtread.jpg" width="400" alt height="100"><br>
<img src="sadretsad.jpg" alt height="100"><br>
```